# Append unix timestamp to files with space using a script

Tags: bash, shell-script, timestamps

This script works fine for all files recursively as well but it does not name files that has space in between. For example it throws error for the files "this is a test.txt" or "test file.txt"

Any idea how to fix it?

```
   #!/bin/bash
   dir="/data/"
   #for filename in `ls -1t $dir/`
   for filename in `find $dir -type f`
   do
   i=".`date -r $filename +%s`"
   mv $filename $filename$i

   done
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead :

```
 #!/bin/bash

 shopt -s globstar # require bash4 : recursive

 dir="/data/"
 for filename in $dir**; do
    i=".$(date -r $filename +%s)"
    mv "$filename" "$filename$i"
 done
```

If you don't have bash4 :

```
find "$dir" -type f -exec bash -c '
    i=".$(date -r $1 +%s)"
    mv "$1" "$1$i"
' -- {} \;
```

Don't forget to double quote every variables !

See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes, http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments and http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words.

Comment: shopt: globstar: invalid shell option  error

Comment: Also did you mean for filename in $dir*.* or just ** ? This won't rename any folders right?

Comment: Have you seen `bash4` ? That means you need bash >= 4.*. `bash -version`

Comment: Okay updating it.

Comment: Sorry! I can't update to bash. I'm running on 5.6 CentOS and it  is not fetching bash 4. Is there any way to do it using find like my old script?

Comment: POST edited accordingly

Comment: you should completely drop the globstar bit - it adds nothing but confusion to this - as you 've seen. Probably `find` is the way to go here. That recursion call is *incredibly slow* on a large filesystem by the way. And it blows up when symlinks screw up the tree.

Answer (score 2):

Try a null-delimited while loop instead (and remember to quote all the variable expansions):

```
#!/bin/bash

dir="/data/"
while IFS= read -r -d '' filename
do
  i="$(date -r "$filename" +%s)"
  mv -- "$filename" "$filename.$i"
done < <(find "$dir" -type f -print0)
```

Comment: where should I add the directory path?

Comment: @money I have clarified the answer

Comment: Okay this works. But it has 2 dots after file name. I need only one. Instead of "Test filename.txt..1213213" I need it as "Test filename.txt.1213213"

Comment: @money are you sure you didn't retain an extra `.` in the expression for `i`? I moved it for stylistic reasons

Comment: I think it did have a . I'm double checking this.

Comment: This worked! Thank you. I don't know who voted you as negative answer. I can't vote at all

Comment: @money you can, however, [accept the answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). Please do so since it will not only reward the person who helped you but also mark the question as answered.